# Inequality for intermediate derivatives

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $D\subseteq$ be an open, bounded Lipshitz domain, $1\le p<\infty$, $u \in W^{2,p}(D)$ and $\delta>0$. Show that there exists $C=C(\delta)>0$ such that

\begin{align}
\|Du\|_{L^p(D)} \le \delta\|D^2u\|_{L^p(D)}+C\|u\|_{L^p(D)}.
\end{align}

The following proof is adapted from Troianiello's book Elliptic differential equations and obstacle problems:

Assume to the  contrary that there exist
    $\delta_0>0$ and $u_k\in W^{2,p}(D), k\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
    $\|u_k\|_{W^{2,p}(D)}=1$ and
    \begin{align}
 \|Du_k\|_{L^p(D)}
 >\varepsilon_0 \|D^2u_k\|_{L^p(D)}
 +k\|u_k\|_{L^p(D)}.
 \end{align}
    Therefore,
    $$
 \|u_k\|_{L^p(D)}
 <
 \frac{1}{k}
 \|Du_k\|_{L^p(D)}
 <
 \frac{1}{k}
 \|u_k\|_{W^{2,p}(D)}
 =\frac{1}{k},
 $$
    and hence, $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \|u_k\|_{L^p(D)}=0$.
    Since $\|u_k\|_{W^{2,p}(D)}=1$, by virtue of the Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem
($W^{2,p}(D) \subseteq W^{1,p}(D)$ compactly), 
    there exists $\{u_{k_l}\}_{l=1}^\infty \subset \{u_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ and $u\in W^{1,p}(D)$ 
    such that 
    \begin{align}
 \lim\limits_{l\to \infty}
 \|u_{k_l}-u\|_{W^{1,p}(D)}=0.
 \end{align}
    Combining  this with $\lim\limits_{l\to \infty}\|u_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)}=0$ and 
    $$
 \|u\|_{L^p(D)}
 \le 
 \|u_{k_l}-u\|_{L^p(D)}
 +
 \|u_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)}
 \le 
 \|u_{k_l}-u\|_{W^{1,p}(D)}
 +\|u_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)},
 $$
    we have $\|u\|_{L^p(D)}=0$, so $u=0$.
    Therefore,
    $$
 \|Du_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)}
 =
 \|Du_{k_l}-Du\|_{L^p(D)}
 <
 \|u_{k_l}-u\|_{W^{1,p}(D)}
 \to 0
 $$
    as $l\to \infty$. Consequently,
$$
 \|D^2u_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)}
 <
 \frac{1}{\delta_0}
 \|Du_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)} \to 0
 $$
    as $l\to \infty$.
    Since $$\|u_{k_l}\|_{W^{2,p}(D)} \sim 
 \|u_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)}
 +
 \|Du_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)}
 +\|D^2u_{k_l}\|_{L^p(D)},$$ we have
    $\lim\limits_{l\to \infty} \|u_{k_l}\|_{W^{2,p}(D)}=0$, contradicting 
    $\|u_{k_l}\|_{W^{2,p}(D)}=1$.

I have two questions:

1. How do we guarantee that the constant $C$ depend on $\delta>0$ only and independent of domain $D$?
2. Is there a direct proof of this inequality (not using contradiction)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe $C$ should depend on the domain.

Comment: @StanPalasek: I am also not sure that $C$ does not depend on domain. Do you have some examples? Do you know where is the dependence of domain in the proof of theorem?

Comment: Probably by scaling the domain and dilating the function you can show that arbitrarily large constants are needed.

Comment: For a constructive proof, see Gilbarg-Trudinger Chapter 7, the section on extension and interpolation. In particular, for $u\in W^{k,p}_0(D)$ they have $C = 36 n^2$ independent of $D$ (note it is not $W^{k,p}(D)$).

Comment: @StanPalasek. Maybe, now I understand. If one start with $D=B(1)$, then using substitution for $D=B(r)$, we get a constant $C/r$? So, the constant is large for small ball.